# JQuery animation timing small issue

Tags: jquery, animation

Okay, I've almost got this thing finished! Many thanks to all who have helped / showed me the way. I voted you up as much as I could. Now I just have one last question -

Please see this fiddle and click on the "increase" button: http://jsfiddle.net/2C8fy/6/

When you click on the increase button, how can I get the images to slide smoothly to the left? The first one does it but the others don't slide. I've tried using "left: '-=50px'" in the animation function, but this seems to mess up the spacing between the images (it's still there it's just commented out. Just take out the comment slashes if you want to see what it does...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Html / CSS Work:**

Make the images container `#basic_div` absolute. Wrap the images inside the container with another div, call it `.frame` or something.

Make the container `position: relative`, and the wrapping div inside the container `position absolute;left:0;top:0;`.

You can now animate the inside div instead of the images.

**JS:**

On decrease animate the frames 'left' property 50 pixels to the left. On animation end, remove the first image, and reset the frame `left` property to 0 as soon as the first image has no layout anymore. This ensures that no jumping occurs.

Comment: Thanks. You put me on the right track and I could understand what you meant but I was a but confused at first which elements needed to be positioned absolute and relative. I ended up going with just making "basic_div" relative. That worked and now it's working just like I need it to. Thanks for your help!